# Derivada simbólica de una ecuación dada por el usuario

Tags: python, sympy

Quería hacer un programa en este lenguaje de programación en el cual se digite una ecuación y posteriormente mostrar la derivada. Para las derivadas simbólicas se utiliza sympy, pero no se como poder operar con la ecuaciones que son dadas por un input o si de esta manera no es posible ¿Cómo puedo desarrollar este programa ?

Comment: Sería bueno que mostraras qué has intentado. Así como está planteada, la pregunta es demasiado genérica. Intenta proporcionar un [mcve] tras leer [ask].

Answer (score 1):

La expresión que quieras derivar se ha de derivar con respecto a un símbolo. Ese símbolo (típicamente x) deberá estar creado previamente, y el usuario ha de saber que su expresión deberá contener x.

Cumpliendo las premisas anteriores, lo siguiente podría funcionar:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

x = symbols('x', real=True)
s = input("Introduzca la expresión a derivar (respecto a x):")
ps=parse_expr(s,locals())
derivada = diff(ps,x)
print("La derivada es: ", derivada)
```

Ejemplo de ejecución:

```
Introduzca la expresión a derivar (respecto a x): sin(x)**2 + (b-x)**3
La derivada es:  -3*(b - x)**2 + 2*sin(x)*cos(x)
```